# Как осуществить выборку из текста?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, веб-программирование

В переменной имеется текст, например:

```
string a = "{"anchor":"aaabbbccc==","members":[{"userId":"111"},{"userId":"2222"},{"userId":"333"},{"userId":"444"}],"has_more":true}
```

(сегментов типа {"userId":"XXX"} может быть и больше)
Как сделать так, чтобы на выходе мы получили то что ниже?:

111
222
333
444

(либо в текстовом файле, либо в Text.Box)
У меня была идея сделать парсинг текста, ведь нужные мне места всегда находятся между {"userId":" и "}
То есть можно сделать цикл, который будет пробегать через текст этой переменной и выбирать всё что между {"userId":" и "}, помещая выражения в новые строки
Но как это сделать? Есть идейки? Спасибо заранее

Comment: Вам нужно получить только UserID?

Comment: Да. Все UserID из текста

Answer (score 1):

Можно сделать с помощью регулярки:

```
string a = "{\"anchor\":\"aaabbbccc==\",\"members\":[{\"userId\":\"111\"},{\"userId\":\"2222\"},{\"userId\":\"333\"},{\"userId\":\"444\"}],\"has_more\":true}";

var results = Regex.Matches(a, "\"userId\":\"([0-9]+)\"").Cast<Match>().Select(x => x.Groups[1]); // массив со значениями
```